# Prevent firing of OnChange function after field is updated on server side

Tags: javascript, c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

When I register an OnChange function to a field, it gets fired if the field is updated on a plugin on the server side (On Dynamics Crm 2015)

Can this behavior be prevented (In a supported way)?

**Example code:**

**1. Client side:**

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("org_myfield").addOnChange(function () { alert("org_myfield was changed") });
```

**2. Server side:**

```
internal void OnPreUpdateRequest(org_myentity target, org_myentity preImage)
{
    target.org_myfield = "some value";
}
```

**3. Result** (after saving the record and plugin finished its run):

```
"org_myfield was changed"
```

**Required result:** The alert should not be fired.

Comment: wait, what? this is impossible :) how are you achieving this in fact?

Comment: The above is exactly what I did. As I understand, this is an expected behavior per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334481.aspx): "This event [OnChange] also occurs when data changes on the server are retrieved to update a field when the form is refreshed, such as after a record is saved."

Comment: on form load oh yes, I thought on idling :)

Comment: Note I'm not talking about OnLoad event

Comment: By default ExecutionContext will be sent as first param in EventHandler. try if any difference you can see.. good luck

Comment: So, when it should be fired? What case? Only user input? Only script changes on that field?

Comment: @Sxntk, that's right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is what you are trying to get:

1. When user makes change on this field, call the JavaScript on change function;

2. When the record is saved, a plugin might change the value of the field as well;

3. If the field value is altered by the plugin, skip the JavaScript function.

If this is correct, I would try this way:

Remove the `onChange` event from the field, instead check the field status in `onSave` event of the form. 

Use `Xrm.Page.getAttribute("org_myfield").getIsDirty()` to determine whether the user makes any change on the field. It only checks the changes on client side so it won't be affected by plugin.