# Why Javascript onchange event triggering when Updating lookup value from Plugin (Prevent) in MSCRM 365?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

I am facing issue while I am updating lookup value from plugin(pre-Operation).

I have written a java script function on-change of lookup field but when I am updating lookup value from plugin, on-change event triggers. I am not changing value manually.

Can anyone clarify?

any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks
Amar

Comment: So what makes you think that it's not normal?

Comment: I think it should trigger When Manually changed by user.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent firing of OnChange function after field is updated on server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47079719/prevent-firing-of-onchange-function-after-field-is-updated-on-server-side)

Answer (score 0):

That's because the field onchange event is is triggered whenever the field changes, whether client-side or server-side. Thus onChange will be triggered if the field is changed via workflow/plugin. If you want to avoid this, use on save instead. As Arun mentioned, this is a duplicate of this question: [Prevent firing of OnChange function after field is updated on server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47079719/prevent-firing-of-onchange-function-after-field-is-updated-on-server-side)